# How to make an enterprise app that does not contain uninstall option in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am making an enterprise application for iPhone, it does not contain uninstall option how to make this application in ios. Lang:Objective c

Comment: You can restrict uninstall in code, you will need MDM server to restrict the device and disallow the uninstall.

Comment: can you please explain clearly i didn't get you if you know any tutorial share the link @rckoenes

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create iOS app that could not be removed.

But, you can use iPhone/iPad/iPod settings to forbid uninstall:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204396

Or you can use MDM to setup restrictions:

> Configuring devices with MDM To enable management, securely enroll
>   your devices with an MDM server using a configuration profile—an XML
>   file that allows you to distribute configuration information to an iOS
>   device. These profiles automate the configuration of settings,
>   accounts, restrictions, and credentials; they can be delivered through
>   MDM   if you need to configure many devices and prefer a low-touch,
>   over-the-air deployment. Profiles can also   be sent as an email
>   attachment, downloaded from a web page, or installed on devices
>   through Apple Configurator 2.

Take a look at MDM docs:

http://images.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Deployment_Overview_Business.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is no uninstall on iOS, you can just remove any app you installed. You press the app and after some time the icon wobble and a cross is show, click the cross and the app gets removed.

You however restrict device and disallow the user to remove some app, this is done with [Mobile Device management `MDM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management).

You can register devices to an MDM server and push setting to the device, allow/disallow install of apps, force install of apps, restrict apps, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can prevent Deleting ( uninstalling ) apps is to go to

Setting app->General->Restrictions

From there 'Enable Restrictions' and setting up a password for parental control,

Then turn off 'Deleting App' switch control.

This is usually good for devices belonging to a company or an organization in the hands of members or employees. Otherwise you can not prevent users from deleting an app from their devices they own.